# How to return a new 1D array containing the count of elements in another 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

How would I return an integer array that counts the number of elements of another 2D array that are true in each column

Here is a 2D array example:

```
000
X0X
0X0
```

The int array would have to return the "0"s of each column (0 being a boolean variable meaning that a light is on)

It would return {2, 2, 2}

Here is what I did:

```
public static int[] totalLightsOn(Light[][] sign) {
        int[] lightOn = new int[sign[0].length];

        if (sign.length < 1 || sign[0].length < 1) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < sign[0].length; i++) {
            int count = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < sign.length; j++) {
                lightOn[i] = count;
                if (sign[i][j].isOn()) {
                    count++;

                }

            }

        }
        return lightOn;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: if your array is of size `m x n`, `sign[0].length` will return `n`, but you want `m`, ie. number of rows in the array.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is of size `m x n`, `sign[0].length` will return `n`, but you want `m`, ie. number of rows in the array.

So, you should use `sign.length` instead while initializing `lightOn`.

Also notice inside the loop, if condition is changed from `sign[i][j] to sign[j][i]`

Here is the code that should work:

```
public static int[] totalLightsOn(Light[][] sign) {
        int[] lightOn = new int[sign.length];

        if (sign.length < 1 || sign[0].length < 1) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < sign[0].length; i++) {
            int count = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < sign.length; j++) {
                if (sign[j][i].isOn()) {
                    count++;

                }
            lightOn[i] = count
            }

        }
        return lightOn;
    }
```

Comment: Sure, you can accept the answer in that case :) @shlop14
Also, I hope you were able to figure out why `i,j` changed to `j,i`